# Which low-number network ports required in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, port

Are iPhone apps are free to access any low-number network port required? Is there any thing called low-number network port in iOS ? Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this:   [TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944)

As it's written at the above article, Many of these ports are well-known, industry-standard ports. You should use a known port only for its purpose (for example - use port 443 only for https).

If you have your own custom protocol, use a port that isn't one of the common ports. For that - choose a big number. You might also run a test to check that the port you chose is not already been used.

In addition - see this thread 
[How to select a static port number for a custom app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275430/how-to-select-a-static-port-number-for-a-custom-app)

And finally, you can also check here, where you can see **a lot** of port numbers usage:   https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=1

Answer (score 0):

iOS is based on Darwin UNIX, so I would use that as a *rough* guide to what's acceptable with regard to selecting ports to communicate on.

Here is a list of [well known low ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Comment: Can you explain that what actually low number ports are ? Don't know much about them. It will be helpful for more R&D.

Comment: Well Thanks for the link, but that does not specify clearly what i need to know , is it true that apps are freely accessible ? "Low-number ports" are specified on what basis ?

Comment: to be clear, low port means range of port numbers <10K, that are known for various predefined uses. They are historically inherited over the years